# Need help creating pid process tree

Tags: linux, awk, pid

I have a project that I'm doing. This is my first time creating a pid process tree. the tree is suppose to show great grandparent, grandparent, parent, child, grandchild, great grandchild

The instructions:
write a script which takes a pid as its
argument and prints the following
information:
a) command name
b) any network connections,
c) repeat (a) and (b) for up to 3 ancestor
processes and up to 3 generations of
descendents

This is the code I have so far

```
ps -al | awk '{print $4,$5}'
parents[pid]=ppid
echo $parents
```

the output of this code is suppose to show the list of the PID's and PPID's but it's not working. I need help. Also I'm using linux to write this code.

this is the new code I created.

```
    function treeOfLife(){
    pid=$$
    myParent=$PPID 
    myParent=$(ps -al | awk '{print $4,$5}')
    GPPID=$(grep PPid: /proc/$$/status | awk '{print $2}')
    echo $myParent $GPPID
}
treeOfLife $myParent $GPPID
```

When I run the code this is what I get for the output. PID PPID 1304 1167 1506 1304 1507 1506 1508 1507 1509 1507 1304

Comment: Seems to me that a simple array with pids as the key and parents as the values would let you write functions that would walk up and down the tree to find (grand)parent and (grand)child relationships. Traverse the array twice matching key to values to find grandparents. Traverse it twice matching values to keys to find grandchildren. But what output are you *looking* for? Just a list of pids? Or something like what `ps -ejH` shows in Linux, or `ps axd` in FreeBSD?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on linux you may find it easier to simply read `/proc/[pid]/status`.  e.g.

```
# echo $$        
167
# grep PPid /proc/$$/status
PPid:   158
```

See also

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html

Comment: You should probably add this to your original question so that it's readable.

Comment: A quick note:  You probably don't need to use both `ps | awk` and `grep /proc | awk`.  You can probably do everything you need with just awk.

Comment: I added more stuff to it @jq170727

Comment: It looks like you're making progress but you need to do some cleanup and some more thinking about the problem.  More specifically, it should be easy to find the ids of a process's ancestors without making too many assumptions but if you're going to try and find the ids of the descendents then your process is going to need to create some children and those processes will need to create children and so forth so that your process will have some descendents to examine.

Comment: right now I'm trying to get the process ID's of the grandparent and great grandparent. Did the output look correct? I couldn't tell because of the way the output looks.

Comment: once you set `pid=$$`, why do you keep using `$$` in you calls to `/proc/$$/status`. You realize you can do `/proc/$pid/status`, `/proc/$GPPID/status` etc? AND you **really** need to update the body of your Q with your best attempt to solve your problem. Why do readers here need to try and decipher code and output in comments, when a properly formatted Q makes it easy for everyone. (If you make this correction, then you should delete any of your comments that are duplicate info). Good luck.

Comment: If you have it installed, you can use `pstree -p` to check your process tree.

Comment: But you're on the right track, and its a good idea to get this basic framework fixed first, before trying to add the extra bells and whistles about network connections etc. Good luck.